# Uploaded PHP form onto iPage server and it's not working

Tags: php

Need help with some PHP. I am not an expert on PHP but i have designed a simple html contact form with PHP and google re-captcha v3. when i upload the form on my server it works with no issues but on iPage it doesn't do anything. doesn't even give me an error or redirect. Here is my form code, PHP and recaptcha script:

```
<?php // Check if form was submitted:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['recaptcha_response'])) {

// Build POST request:
$recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$recaptcha_secret = 'xxxxx';
$recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];

// Make and decode POST request:
$recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' .    $recaptcha_response);
$recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);

// Take action based on the score returned:
if ($recaptcha->score >= 0.5) {
        $myemail = "test@test.com \n";
        $headers = "From: {$_REQUEST['email']}";
        $message .= "

        ____________________________________

        The following form was filled out on your website.

        First Name: {$_REQUEST['first_name']}

        Last Name: {$_REQUEST['last_name']}

        E-mail Address: {$_REQUEST['email']}

        Primary Phone: {$_REQUEST['phone']}

        Interested in: {$_REQUEST['purpose']}

        Message: {$_REQUEST['contact_message']}

        ";
        $sub="Customer filled out a form on your website";
        $message2 .= "
        Thank You
        Your Request Has Been Received.

        ";
        $headers2 = "From: test@test.com \n";
        $sub2="Thank You. Your Request Has Been Received";
        $message = stripslashes($message);
        $message2 = stripslashes($message2);
        $message = strip_tags($message);
        $message2 = strip_tags($message2);
        // INSERT YOUR OWN EMAIL ADDRESS BELOW
        mail($myemail, $sub, $message, $headers);
        mail($_REQUEST['email'], $sub2, $message2, $headers2);
        //var_dump($test1);
        //var_dump($test2);
        header("Location: thankyou.php", true, 302);
        die();
    } else {
    // Not verified - show form error
}

} ?>


<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=xxxx"></script>
     <script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.execute('xxx', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
            var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
            recaptchaResponse.value = token;
        });
    });
</script>



<form class="wpcf7" method="POST">
                <fieldset style="width: 100%">

                    <select class="wpcf7-select" name="purpose">
                                                <option value="">Interested in</option>
                                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                                <option value="B">B</option>
                                            </select>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>

                <input type="text" class="wpcf7-text" id="First-Name" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" data-validation="required"/>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>

                <input type="text" class="wpcf7-text" id="Last-Name" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" data-validation="required"/>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>

                <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" class="wpcf7-text" data-validation="email"/>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                <input type="text" class="wpcf7-text" id="Phone-Number" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" data-validation="required"/>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset style="width: 100%">
                <textarea rows="5" class="wpcf7-textarea" id="Message" placeholder="Comments/Questions" name="contact_message"></textarea>
              </fieldset>
             <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse"> 

              <input type="submit" class="wpcf7-submit" value="Submit" />

            </form>
```

Comment: You should be getting an error here but haven't enabled error reporting.

Comment: I'm not that great with PHP. Could you give me an example?

Comment: `$message .= "....` < that is the offending line (so far). You need to pre-define an empty string before it, such as `$message = "";` without the leading dot.

Comment: thank you but it is still not working. With or without the dot.